# linking methods from an enum to member variables of client class

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, enums, encapsulation

The following enum structure performs certain operations while remaining agnostic to the client class (for encapsulation reasons)

```
    public enum MyEnum implements Commands{
    A{
        public int method1(int varY) {          
            return varY+2;
        }

        public MyEnum method2(){
                       return MyEnum.B;
              }

             //...other methods implementing Commands interface
    },
    B{

        public int method1(int varX) {
            return varX-2;
        }


               public MyEnum method2(){
                       return MyEnum.C;
              }

        //...other methods implementing Commands interface
    },
    C{

        public int method1(int varY) {
            return varY-2;
        }

        public MyEnum method2(){
                        return MyEnum.D;
               }


              //...other methods implementing Commands interface
    },
    D{

        public int method1(int varX) {
            return varX+2;
        }

        public MyEnum method2(){
                      return MyEnum.A;
                 }


             //...other methods implementing Commands interface
    }
```

The client class

```
    public class Client {
    private int varX;
    private int varY;
    private MyEnum enum;

    MyEnum getEnum(){
        return enum;
    }

    int varX(){
        return varX;
    }

    int getVarY(){
        return varY;
    }

    public Client(int varX, int varY, MyEnum enum){
        this.varX = varX;
        this.varY = varY;
        this.enum = enum;
    }

    public void performMethod1(MyEnum enum){        
        varX = getEnum().method1(getVarX()); //???
        varY = getEnum().method1(getVarY()); //???
    }

     public void performMethod2(...){
                enum = getEnum().method2();
      }
}
```

My question is how to link the specific implementations of method1() belonging to MyEnum.A and MyEnum.C so that they operate on Client class member varY, and the method1() implementations of MyEnum.B and MyEnum.D to operate only on Client class member variable varX.

For example within a main() method:

```
Client aClient = new Client(aVarX, aVarY, anEnum);    
aClient.performMethod1(aClient.getEnum());
```

So, depending in the current enum state, the above statement should operate only on varX or varY and change the state on aClient.

Let's say for:

```
aClient.performMethod1(MyEnum.A);
```

The state of **aClient** represented by **varY** should be changed to **varY+2**. varX should remain unchanged.

As you can see by the simple naming convention, at this time varX in MyEnum is not linked to varX in Client class in any way. My thoughts lean toward the type of the variables. Since I am working with primitives (int) there is no way to distinguish..

Would you recommend I create different custom types for each of the varX and varY (wrap them somehow?) in Client class?

I hope I am not too verbose with the question. Please let me know in case I am not being clear with it. Many thanks.

Comment: In "performMethod1(...)", you use "getEnum().method1(...)" so its the enum of the Client that do method1 NOT the "enum" parameter.

I am not sure if you want to use the parameter "enum" to do method1 or what? Please clearify more.

Comment: Yes, the Client simply delegates to the different enumerations in the MyEnum class to perform the method logic.

But since MyEnum is a member variable of the Client as well, to chage state of the Client I would need to pass MyEnum to the other methods.. like method2(). Is that any clearer? Thanks for your comment

Comment: I updated both the MyEnum and Client code, to show that Client delegates to MyEnum which keeps a reference of, and changes the state of that enum which is an attribute of Client's. -- The aim is to do the same with the varX, varY Client members

Comment: >> The aim is to do the same with the varX, varY Client members

How can you do that without naming Client? As I said earlier either the enum has to know about the Client or the Client has to switch on the enum. Since enums are used for switching, that seems the better way to do it :-)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "naming the Client"? As for the Client switching on the enum, that is certainly a way to go, but the objective is to avoid switch or if statements

Answer (score 1):

You want different things to happen to the `Client` depending on different values of the `MyEnum`. If the `MyEnum` has to be client agnostic then either the `Client` will have to recognize different states of the `MyEnum` (a switch in `Client.performMethod1`) or a separate processor class will have implement that logic.

Comment: I see the point, but the objective is to avoid switch/if statements in the Client. The enum has all the alternatives already built-in

For example in another method not shown in the MyEnum, let's say method2, I could operate on the MyEnum cases itself. And then, in Client I could wrap this in performMethod2(MyEnum enum) and change the enum state of Client

Comment: I edited my original post to include method2() in MyEnum. It is better shown now that, Client has the ability to simply delegate to MyEnum by performMethod2(), keep its state and behavior encapsulated, while MyEnum is basically Client agnostic - no references to any objects that use its enumerations. -- So since this is possible with a MyEnum variable, it should be possible with the varX and varY primitives, right?